# Resort specific column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, `df`, of a few thousand rows and five columns: `course`, `student_ID`, `assignment`, `teacher_comment`, `teacher_comment_type`. Each row corresponds to unique a unique `teacher_comment`; there are only some 30 different courses and 100 different assignments total.

I easily used `df.groupby(['assignment', 'teacher_comment_type']).count()` to generate a new dataframe whereby I can see each `teacher_comment_type` that a given assignment ever received for any student, across the board — and also how many times that comment type was given for a certain assignment. I now want to resort the count column locally for each `assignment`, but I'm struggling to do so.

In other words, right now, I have:

```
Essay 1   | formatting error | 4
          | punctuation      | 5
          | style feedback   | 2
          | ultimate score   | 1
Project B | formatting error | 3
          | punctuation      | 5
          | style feedback   | 7
          | ultimate score   | 1
```

And so on. Automatically, the second column is locally alphabetized (by locally, I mean for each assignment name in the left column). But I want to reorder locally by that third column — in order from greatest to least number. Does that make sense? I've fiddled around with `.sort_values` to no avail (it will alter the entire structure of the dataframe, failing to maintain that "local" integrity — the organization by assignment name).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `value_counts` instead

```
df.groupby('assignment').teacher_comment_type.value_counts()

assignment  teacher_comment_type
Essay 1     punctuation             5
            formatting error        4
            style feedback          2
            ultimate score          1
Project B   style feedback          7
            punctuation             5
            formatting error        3
            ultimate score          1
Name: teacher_comment_type, dtype: int64
```